# JavaScript: Combine list of item values by common item field

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to combine items in my `list` array so that there are only unique `date` fields in the resulting array. I also need the `amount` field of items in the resulting array to be the total of any items from the original array that share the same `date` value.

The format of data in my `list` array looks like this:

```
var list = [
  {amount: "10", date: "2000-03-01"},// These three records have same date 
  {amount: "20", date: "2000-03-01"},// field, need to combine into
  {amount: "30", date: "2000-03-01"},// one record
  {amount: "50", date: "2000-03-03"},
  {amount: "100", date: "2000-03-05"},
  {amount: "30", date: "2000-03-06"},// These two records have same date 
  {amount: "70", date: "2000-03-06"},// field, need to combine
  {amount: "80", date: "2000-03-10"},
]
```

I need to convert the list above to this:

```
var expectedList = [
  {amount: "60", date: "2000-03-01"}, // combined item
  {amount: "50", date: "2000-03-03"},
  {amount: "100", date: "2000-03-05"},
  {amount: "100", date: "2000-03-06"},// combined item
  {amount: "80", date: "2000-03-10"},
]
```

Comment: By _"combine"_, do you mean _"sum"_?

Comment: Not just "sum". A new list as well

Comment: Have you tried anything.. you just posted 2 blocks of code (task and result) and that's it, it looks to me that you did not put any effort?

Comment: I think you misunderstood. Are the `amount` values _"combined"_ by summing them together?

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev I am newbie for JS, I did not have much experience for most of array methods, such as entries(). So I did try something myself, just cannot solve it. That is why I posted here.

Comment: Fair enough, but you should always post your code even if it's not working, it will better your chances to get an answer for something less trivial in future.

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev Cheers, I will do better next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution could be via `Array.reduce()` where you would first build an intermediate mapping that maps the `date` key, to an aggregated total of `amount` values. You'd then transform the mapping back to a flat array via   `Object.entries()` as shown below:

```js
var list = [
  {amount: "10", date: "2000-03-01"},
  {amount: "20", date: "2000-03-01"},
  {amount: "30", date: "2000-03-01"},
  {amount: "50", date: "2000-03-03"},
  {amount: "100", date: "2000-03-05"},
]

const result = Object.entries(list.reduce((mapping, item) => {
  
  /* During each iteration of reduce over the list, retrieve
  the totalled "amount" for this item's "date" */
  mapping[ item.date ] = mapping[ item.date ] || 0
  
  /* Increment the "total" for this "date" by the "amount" of
  the current item, and persist into the map */
  mapping[ item.date ] += Number.parseInt(item.amount)
  
  return mapping
  
}, {})).map(([amount, date]) => {
  
  /* Object.entries() returns a list of key/value pairs from the 
  mapping created by our reduce() step. Here we transform each
  key/value pair of the mapping back to the desired format */
  return { amount, date }
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use reduce function to achieve that.

```
list.reduce(( prev, curr )=>{
    // parse string amount into number for calculation
    curr.amount = parseInt(curr.amount);

    let index;

    if ((index = prev.findIndex( item => item.date == curr.date )) > -1 )
        prev[index].amount += curr.amount;
    else
        prev.push( curr );

    return prev;

}, []);
```

Output:

```
[ { amount: 60, date: '2000-03-01' },
  { amount: 50, date: '2000-03-03' },
  { amount: 100, date: '2000-03-05' } ]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want simple and easy to understand code, use the code from the snippet below.

The code below basically loops through the list, and then loops through output to check if the dates from the 2 elements are the same. If so, it adds the amounts and sets the value of `found` to true. At the end of the [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), if `found` is still false (if we haven't found an element in which the dates match), we push the value to the output array.

```js
var list = [
  {amount: "10", date: "2000-03-01"},
  {amount: "20", date: "2000-03-01"},
  {amount: "30", date: "2000-03-01"},
  {amount: "50", date: "2000-03-03"},
  {amount: "100", date: "2000-03-05"},
]
var output = [];
var found = false;

list.forEach(e1 => {
  found = false;
  output.forEach(e2 => {
    if (e1.date == e2.date) {
      e2.amount = parseInt(e2.amount) + parseInt(e1.amount);
      found = true;
    }
  });
  
  if (!found) {
    output.push(e1);
  }
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems a reasonably simple two step process. First, reduce the array to a map of dates to amount sums, then convert the values of that map to a new array.

```js
var list = [
  {amount: "10", date: "2000-03-01"},
  {amount: "20", date: "2000-03-01"},
  {amount: "30", date: "2000-03-01"},
  {amount: "50", date: "2000-03-03"},
  {amount: "100", date: "2000-03-05"}
]

const expectedList = Array.from(list.reduce((map, {amount, date}) => {
  return map.set(date, (map.get(date) || 0) + parseInt(amount))
}, new Map())).map(([date, amount]) => ({ amount, date }))

console.info(expectedList)
```

Comment: Wouldn't a simple reduce + array accumulator be better, this kind of seems a bit convoluted solution for such straightforward task, given the fact that you are converting to array at the end. Those destructors are a bit too much as well, in my opinion at least. P.S. Are there some memory/performance benefits in this?

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev reducing to an array would then require searching for the right record in each iteration, making it `O(n^2)` time complexity. Reducing to a `Map` (or even a plain object like [Dacre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54994488/283366)) makes it `O(2n)`

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev the use of object desctructuring is totally subjective. Personally, I think it looks neater but you're just as welcome to your opinion

Comment: Agree, I did not think of the complications for big (n) items in the array, I just thought that it might be overkill for those ~5 objects but you are right.

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev I always assume the data in the question is just a sample 

Answer (score 1):

```js
var list = [
  {amount: "10", date: "2000-03-01"},
  {amount: "20", date: "2000-03-01"},
  {amount: "30", date: "2000-03-01"},
  {amount: "50", date: "2000-03-03"},
  {amount: "100", date: "2000-03-05"},
]

const builtObject = list.reduce((acc, {date, amount}) => {
  acc[date] = acc[date] || 0
  acc[date] += parseInt(amount)
  return acc
}, {})

const rs = Object.entries(builtObject).map(([date, amount]) => ({amount, date}))

console.log(rs)
```